# CSS Issue: Below div button are hide when I set margin

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

Please visit images links.
[This image show the target design which I want to design. Text and blue background are image and below there I have a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPSKx.png)

But whenever I set my margin top it will hide.
I want to do this with css. Please tell me any css technique which can show button above the image(image contain text and blue background below there I have a button).
[This image show the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkMNE.png)

Comment: It's incredibly difficult to understand what you're asking. Please read [ask] and include a [mcve] whenever possible

Answer (score 0):

This solution can be found in [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_on_image.asp)

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
}

.container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.container .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container .btn:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Button on Image</h2>
<p>Add a button to an image:</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```